# Creating new Objects for class Integer

Tags: java, integer

I have a simple java class

```
public class T {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
                 Integer x = 0;
                 Integer y = 0;
                 Integer a = 255;
                 Integer b = 255;
                 System.out.println( (x==y) );
                 System.out.println( (a==b) );
 }
```

The console output result is:

```
true
false
```

Why is the output for comparing **x** with **y** are different from comparing **a** with **b**?
Why does Java doesn't create objects for small int values?

Comment: Because == compares references, not values.  Use .equals() for that.

Comment: why for small int values java don't create new objects?

Comment: why are you using the object Integer rather than the simple primitive int?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Look up "interning" - it's turned on for `Integer`s between -128 and +127.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare objects in Java use `.equals()`.

```
public class T {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
                 Integer x = 0;
                 Integer y = 0;
                 Integer a = 255;
                 Integer b = 255;
                 System.out.println( (x.equals(y)) );
                 System.out.println( (a.equals(b)) );
 }
```

Using `==` you will just compare the references to both objects, which wont be the same.

Use `==` only when comparing *primitive values*.

Comment: This however, is not true for Integers from -128 to 127 (including). Here, the `==` comparison will work.